# failed to create symbolic link: File exists

Tags: maven, maven-3, symlink

I am installing Maven 3, but after I create the symbolic link by:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

then I type:

```
mvn -version
```

But it returns:

```
bash: /usr/bin/mvn: No such file or directory
```

When I go back to `/usr/bin/mvn` I can see the file is there, but why it is not working?